# Ginzburg Criterion (Ising model)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, ising-model

In my statistical field theory class, we were told that we want the magnetization fluctuations in the Ising model to be smaller than their background. Specifically this was written as $$\langle\phi^2\rangle\ll\langle\phi\rangle^2$$ (the Ginzburg criterion).

From my statistics knowledge, the variance of a random variable is given by $$\textrm{Var}(X)=\langle X^2\rangle-\langle X\rangle^2\geq0.$$
In this case, how is it ever possible that $\langle\phi^2\rangle<\langle\phi\rangle^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your situation you are assuming that the order parameter $\phi$ is equal to the fluctuations $\phi = \delta\phi$. In such situation the fluctuations cannot be much smaller than the order parameter itself, and the mean-field theory does not make sense. As such, the Ginzburg criterion is not satisfied.

In the mean-field theory one suppresses the fluctuations by setting them to zero. Of course this is justified only if on average the fluctuations are much smaller than the magnitude of the mean-field itself. Therefore the Ginzburg criterion is actually written as:
$$\left< \left(\delta \phi\right)^2\right>\ll \left< \phi^2\right>,$$

where $\delta \phi$ is the fluctuation from the mean-field. Mathematically, one can then write the Ginzburg criterion as

$$\frac{\sqrt{\left<\phi^2\right> - \left<\phi\right>^2}}{\left<\phi\right>}\ll 1,$$
i.e. the relative fluctuations of the $\phi$ field are negligible.

Comment: What is $\delta\phi$? I was under the impression that the "fluctuations" are $\langle\phi^2\rangle$, and the mean field (squared) is $\langle\phi\rangle^2$.

Comment: $\delta \phi$ is the fluctuation away from the mean field. It would be rather strange if for a constant field $\phi = 1$ one had a non-zero measure of fluctuation, as would be the case in your definition. I also updated my answer to make matters clearer.

Comment: Oh so are you defining $\langle(\delta\phi)^2\rangle\equiv\langle\phi^2\rangle-\langle\phi\rangle^2$? And strange that my professor used $\langle\phi^2\rangle$ instead of $\langle(\delta\phi)^2\rangle$

Comment: It makes sense to define the fluctuation of an order parameter away from the mean-field as its variance. Of course, the exact form usually depends on the physics involved. It is also not unusual for lecturers to make mistakes, as you can clearly see that the criterion given by you cannot be satisfied in non-exotic mathematics.

Comment: I think I understand. Then from what you said, $\dfrac{\langle\phi^2\rangle-\langle\phi\rangle^2}{\langle\phi\rangle^2}\ll1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{\langle\phi^2\rangle}{\langle\phi\rangle^2}\approx1 \Rightarrow \langle\phi^2\rangle \approx \langle\phi\rangle^2.$ Perhaps my prof meant to use $\approx$ rather than $\ll$